# Label hover function in highchart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, tooltip, bar-chart

I am using `highchart.js` file for rendering chart in my application. I want to show customize label for Bar chart.

My requirements are if my label name has long text like "`My Label Text Long`", It should show name label like (`My Label...`) in front of bar chart. On mouse over to label name, it should show me a full label name in small `tooltip`. I consulted Highchart documentation but did not find any solution for it.

Comment: add this style "text-overflow:ellipsis" for your label and set the label title="My Label Text Long". Hope it helps.

Comment: hightchart complete document is available on below link:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart
can you tell me under which propety "text-overflow:ellips" exists???

Comment: Can you tell me where you need to clip the text in bar graph of high chart?

Comment: In this below example of bar chart:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic
I need hover funtion for Africa, America etc
mean on rendering it will show like Afri.., Ame...
when will I over the mouse it will show the complete name like Aferica, America

Comment: I think You need to edit your corresponding highchart.js file.

Comment: you can go with formatter, it is present for all the places you need. tell me the exact place where you need this functionality I'll tell you what to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice down the value. As you are getting values in .ja file. Slice those values before displaying.

```
this.value.slice(0,21) +"...";
```