# How to capture the hover event in highcharts labels?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Taking as base the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point:{
           events: {
               mouseOver: function() {alert('hello');}
            }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            ['Shanghai', 23.7],
            ['Lagos', 16.1],
            ['Instanbul', 14.2],
            ['Karachi', 14.0],
            ['Mumbai', 12.5],
            ['Moscow', 12.1],
            ['São Paulo', 11.8],
            ['Beijing', 11.7],
            ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
            ['Delhi', 11.1],
            ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
            ['Seoul', 10.4],
            ['Jakarta', 10.0],
            ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
            ['Tianjin', 9.3],
            ['Tokyo', 9.0],
            ['Cairo', 8.9],
            ['Dhaka', 8.9],
            ['Mexico City', 8.9],
            ['Lima', 8.9]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
});
```

I would like to be able to capture the "hover" event in the labels. After some research in the Highcharts API I only found how to capture the "mouseOver" event in data, not in labels.

The final purpose is to display the tooltip when hovering the label instead of when hovering the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293704/label-hover-function-in-highchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is add a binding for mouseover event to the label(or text)

```
$('.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').bind('mouseover',function(e){
    alert("You hover on "+$(this).text())
});
```

Let's try this [edited version demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvv3pLmo/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [customEvents](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extension which allows do that.